# Knowing current timing of client

Tags: html, jsp

I am developing an web application in Jsp that requires the current time of the user accessing it. I am new to developing web applications. So if anyone give any idea about solving this problem I will be grateful. Thank you.

**EDIT:** I have written the following part of the code with the help of the answers to this post. But even now it is not showing time in result page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTime()
{
   document.getElementById("time").value = new Date().getHours();
 }
</script>
<body onload = "getTime()">
<form name="frm" method="post" action="result.jsp?page=1">
<input name="time" id="time" type="hidden">
</form>
</body>
```

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: make sure result.jsp is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use    `new Date();` in javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can get client date using javascript

```
var clientDate = new Date();
```

now pass this to server in ajax call